# Google App Engine : SimpleAuth : Redirect Url On the Fly

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, redirect, oauth-2.0

i am using SimpleAuth by Alex (https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth) in my GAE application. I have a Jquery Powered Login box in my base template which means users can login from any url inside the application. I want the users to be redirected back to the page they requested to login from. Is there any way we can achieve this with Oauth2 or can we just redirect users back to only a specific url ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SimpleAuth I assume you're probably with webapp2, so @jmort253 examples are not exactly how I would do it (e.g. webapp2 has built-in sessions, so why use yet another library for sessions handling).

Though, conceptually it is correct: what you need is store original URL somewhere in a session before starting authentication process. Then use that stored URL for a final redirect, after successful authentication.

Starting from the example app code of SimpleAuth, what you basically need to change is the [last line of _on_signin()](https://github.com/crhym3/simpleauth/blob/master/example/handlers.py#L166) to redirect users to that original URL they came from (instead of '/profile').

To store the original request URL you could use a simple wrapper, e.g.

```py
def simpleauth_login_required(handler_method):
    """A decorator to require that a user be logged in to access a handler.

    To use it, decorate your get() method like this:


        @simpleauth_login_required
        def get(self):
            user = self.current_user
            self.response.out.write('Hello, ' + user.name())
    """
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.method != 'GET':
            self.abort(400, detail='The login_required decorator '
                'can only be used for GET requests.')

        if self.logged_in:
            handler_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.session['original_url'] = self.request.url
            self.redirect('/my-login-page-where-users-can-choose-auth-method')

    return check_login
```

Now, going back to that _on_signin() redirect line, instead of `self.redirect('/profile')` you'd do something like this:

```py
target = self.session['original_url']
self.redirect(target)
```

A couple notes:

- the example above assumes you have a `logged_in` method which indicates whether the current request is made by an already authenticated user or not;
- you'll probably want to clear 'original_url' from the session (if they successfully authenticated)

The above example's credits go to [webapp2_extras.appengine.users module](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/users.html#module-webapp2_extras.appengine.users).

Comment: Thank Alex, i am indeed using webapp2 and after seeing mort's example i did save it in webapp2 sessions instead of another session lib. Thanks for the great example !

Answer (score 1):

When your user attempts to log in, your app first requests an access token then builds the Google OAuth2 URL. Your app redirects the user to google.com where your user must login. This login URL contains the access token from your server's request to Google. It's tied to that redirect URL for security purposes.

This redirect URL is designed to finalize the login process by returning a successful login operation to your app so that you can then finish logging in the user, registering that user, or doing whatever it is that your app would need to do.

After that, the ball is in your court, and you can program your app to do whatever you want. In other words, Google just cares about getting the request to your secure endpoint. Once that's done, Google no longer cares what you do; it's your app.

Therefore, to redirect your user back to the page he/she was on before logging in, which is an awesome usability improvement, is to do the following:

**Steps to Redirect user:**

1 Before the user logs in, store the page he/she is on in a session.

```
session = appengine_utilities.sessions.Session()
session["target_url"] = "/example_page.html"   # sets keyname to current page
```

2 Next, go ahead and log the user in as normal.

3 After Google redirects the user to your authentication redirect URL, retrieve the target URL from the session:

```
target_url = session['target_url']
```

4 Lastly, redirect the user to this URL.

In short, you can accomplish the goal of redirecting your user to any target URL, so long as you first accept the redirect from Google to a single, established redirect URL.

The session examples came from the [Beaker](http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions.html#using) website. Additionally, [Nick Johnson's Webapps on Appengine Part 5](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Webapps-on-App-Engine-Part-5-Sessions) Blog article dives into sessions with Beaker.